# Word Add In installs despite failure in WIX setup

Tags: c#, wix, office-addins

Creating an installer with WIX toolset v3.10.3.3007 to install an MS Word Add In. How can I make sure a failure does a full rollback?

I am injecting a custom action into the WIX dialog sequence to check a user-entered value. If the check fails I want to fail the installation. **I have a condition to explicitly trigger a failure but even though the failure is triggered, the Add In is still installed and it still runs.** The intentional failure pops up the expected dialog stating:

> ..Setup Wizard ended prematurely because of an error. Your system has not been modified...

Except, my system has been modified. The following is what I think you need to see. I am a WIX novice so I'm not sure if I'm missing something relevant:

install log:

```
...MSI (c) (E8:8C) [18:09:07:125]: Doing action: ActivateCustomAction
MSI (c) (E8:8C) [18:09:07:125]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 18:09:07: ActivateCustomAction. 
Action start 18:09:07: ActivateCustomAction.
MSI (c) (E8:30) [18:09:07:127]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\tekhe\AppData\Local\Temp\MSIC0B9.tmp, Entrypoint: RegisterAddIn
SFXCA: Extracting custom action to temporary directory: C:\Users\tekhe\AppData\Local\Temp\MSIC0B9.tmp-\
SFXCA: Binding to CLR version v4.0.30319
Calling custom action RegisterAddIn!RegisterAddIn.CustomActions.RegisterAddIn
Begin CustomAction1
CustomAction ActivateCustomAction returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 18:09:07: ActivateCustomAction. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (E8:8C) [18:09:07:347]: Doing action: FatalError
MSI (c) (E8:8C) [18:09:07:347]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 18:09:07: FatalError. 
Action start 18:09:07: FatalError.
Action 18:09:07: FatalError. Dialog created
Action ended 18:14:08: FatalError. Return value 2.
Action ended 18:14:08: INSTALL. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (E8:8C) [18:14:08:137]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (c) (E8:A8) [18:14:08:137]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
...
```

Custom Action:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;

namespace RegisterAddIn
{
    public class CustomActions
    {
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult RegisterAddIn(Session session)
        {
            try
            {
                session.Log("Begin CustomAction1");
                string token = session["ActivationToken"];

                if (token == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("No token set yet");
                }

                if (token == "fail it")
                {
                    return ActionResult.Failure;
                }

                session.Log("Captured activation token = " + session["ActivationToken"]);
                return ActionResult.Success;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                session.Log(e.Message);
                return ActionResult.Failure;
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Portion of Product.wxs. `CustomInstallDir` is a copy of the standard WIX `WixUI_InstallDir.wxs` markup, with my custom action added.

```
    <Binary Id="RegisterAddIn" SourceFile="$(var.RegisterAddIn.TargetDir)RegisterAddIn.CA.dll" />
    <CustomAction Id="ActivateCustomAction"
              BinaryKey="RegisterAddIn"
              DllEntry="RegisterAddIn"
              Execute="immediate"
              Return="check" />

   <InstallUISequence>
      <Custom Action="ActivateCustomAction" After="ExecuteAction" />
    </InstallUISequence>

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <!--<MediaTemplate/>-->
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="VTSAddin.cab" EmbedCab="yes"/>
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Word Add In" Level="1">
      ...Component Refs elided
    </Feature>
    <UIRef Id="CustomInstallDir" />
```

CustomInstallDir.wxs section injecting custom dialog (`TokenPromptDlg`) between `VerifyReadyDlg` and `InstallDirDlg` :

```
  <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="3"><![CDATA[NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH AND WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="TokenPromptDlg" Order="4">WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH OR WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID="1"</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="TokenPromptDlg" Order="1">NOT Installed</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="2">Installed AND NOT PATCH</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="2">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>
```

Custom dialog xml (`TokenPromptDialog.wxs`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <UI>
      <Dialog Id="TokenPromptDlg"
              Width="370"
              Height="270"
              Title="Activation">

<!-- Next, Back, Cancel, etc., buttons elided -->

        <Control Id="ActivationTokenLabel"
                 Type="Text" X="10" Y="50" Width="250" Height="18"
                 Text="Enter your validation token" />

        <Control Id="MyTextbox"
           Type="Edit" 
           Property="ActivationToken" 
           X="10" Y="75" Width="250" Height="18" />

      </Dialog>
      <Publish Dialog="TokenPromptDlg"
         Control="Back"
         Event="NewDialog"
         Value="InstallDirDlg" Order="1">1</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="TokenPromptDlg"
               Control="Next"
               Event="NewDialog"
               Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="1">1</Publish>
    </UI>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Normally Failure does rollback the current installation, I experienced that with a PowerPoint add-in. The simplest way to make sure the execution of rollback is by having a (refreshed) look at Programs and Feature list in Control Panel. If your application is listed there then it means rollback didn't happen. Can you please confirm?

Comment: I can confirm it is there. I have been uninstalling it from there repeatedly as I try to figure out the issue. Documentation states a rollback should occur, and the final dialog says the "system has not been modified" so I just don't get it. It's going to make it difficult to enforce payment of registration keys.

Comment: I see. Try with these values. It works well for me. In WixUI_InstallDir.wxs replace the value Execute="immediate" with "deffered". And After="ExecuteAction" with Before="InstallFinalize"

Comment: @AzazulHaq `Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixAction:InstallUISequence/InstallFinalize' in section 'Product:*'.` It is astonishing how difficult this tool is to work with. I'm going to try executing the custom action from within the custom dialog instead of scheduling it and see how it goes.

Comment: My bad, I didn't ask to replace <InstallUISequence> tag with <InstallExecuteSequence> along with other suggestion. I think in start it's difficult to work with Wix toolset but with time as you learn it's one of best Windows installer framework that gives you maximum flexibility in designing, developing and deploying you packages online/offline.